# Domination of a Poisson distribution with a penalization

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables having Poisson distribution with mean $a$ and $b$ respectively. Let $p_1, p_2 \in [0,1]$ be two real numbers such that $p_1 >p_2$. For any given $a$, is there a choice of $b>a$ such that for any non-negative integer $k$,

$$
p_1 \, \,P(X>k) \leq p_2 \, \, P(Y>k),
$$

where $P$ is the law of $X$ and $Y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question as stated is "no".  For instance if $X$ is Poisson of mean $1$, $k = 1$, $p_1 = 1$ and $p_2 = 1/4$, then $P(X > 1) \approx .26$, implying that $$\frac{p_1}{p_2}P(X > 1) > 1.$$